# Multiple directives [actionConfirm, actionConfirm] asking for transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phonegap-build

I have only 1 directive here for this element but I still get this error. Works fine in web but on using phonegap i get this error.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="appointment in appointments track by appointment._id" ng-class="{confirmed: appointment.status === 'confirmed', notconfirmed: (appointment.status === 'not confirmed')}">
  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-flat-danger" action-confirm="$parent.cancelAppt(appointment)" text="Are you sure you want to cancel the appointment?" action-id="{{appointment._id}}">
</div>


(function(){

    'use strict';

    /**
    * @ngInject
    */

    function actionConfirm() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'text': '@',
                'confirmed': '&actionConfirm',
                'actionId': '@'
            },
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'common_loggedin/directives/views/action-confirm.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                element.bind('click', function() {
                    $('#'+  scope.actionId + '.actionConfirmModal').modal('show');
                });

                scope.confirm = function(){
                    scope.confirmed();
                    scope.close();
                }

                scope.close = function(){
                    $('#'+  scope.actionId + '.actionConfirmModal').modal('hide');
                }

            }   
        };

    }

    angular
        .module('xyz')
        .directive('actionConfirm', actionConfirm);

}());
```

Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [actionConfirm, actionConfirm] asking for transclusion on:

Comment: can you post the directive code?

Comment: edited the question with more info